# Why do I get "Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop." with "set -e"?

Tags: makefile, syntax-error, gnu-make

I have a *single line* Makefile that throws the following error: `Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop`. I know there are [dozens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931770/2750819) [of duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/482670/483702) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109724/2750819) with the same error message but most of them suggest something to do with using not using tabs or mysterious special characters.

```
$ cat -e -v -t Makefile 
set -e$

$ make
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

As far as I can see, there are no mysterious special characters. Perhaps there are characters that `cat -e -v -t` doesn't show?

The following works, so I'm guessing it isn't an issue with my `make` installation:

```
$ cat -v -e -t Makefile 
foo:$
^Iecho "Foo"$

$ make
echo "Foo"
Foo
```

Some relevant version and shell information.

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81

$ echo $0
-bash
```

Edit: See comment by @AProgrammer

Note it throws the same error message regardless of what I have below the `set -e`.

```
$ cat -e -v -t Makefile 
set -e$
$
foo:$
^Iecho "foo"$

$ make
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Edit 2:

Note adding `#!/bin/bash` throws the same error message.

```
$ cat -e -v -t Makefile 
#!/bin/bash$
set -e$
$
foo:$
^Iecho "foo"$

$ make
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Edit 3:

Running `set -e` on my shell directly seems to work (it exits the failed `make` call as expected).

```
$ set -e
$ make
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Saving session...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...11 completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: What do you expect the first Makefile to do?

Comment: Nothing. But even if I add anything below it, it throws the same error message.

Comment: @AProgrammer Please see my edit for an example.

Comment: `set -e` at that position in a Makefile in a syntax error.  It is difficult to explain how to fix it without knowing what you want that to do.  (`set -e` is a shell command, but a Makefile is not a shell script and you can't specify at one place initialization for all the shell invocations by make).

Comment: @AProgrammer Maybe I'm missing something but can I not write `set -e` and expect `bash` to immediately exit if there is a non-zero exit code when I run `make`? Are you referring to the fact that I'm missing `#!/bin/bash`? Note I tried that too and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for which `make` would be able to interpret arbitrary shell commands outside of rules.

If you want to exit rules immediately when there is an error, there are several ways to do it, more or less portably.

First, each line in a rule is executed by a separate instance of the shell.  This means that if you don't merge them manually (with `\` and `;`), you'll get the behavior you want if you have one command per line.

Then you can use `set -e` as part of the probably few rules which need it.  For instance;

```
foo:
        set -e; for i in a b c d; mkdir $$i; done
```

With GNU Make, you can change the flags used to call the shell, additionally passing `-e`:

```
.SHELLFLAGS=-ec
```

With POSIX Make, you can change the shell.  I don't know if passing a flag is supported, but it seems so with GNU Make:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh -e
```

but you can always pass a wrapper which set the flags as you want:

```
SHELL=/path/to/mywrapper
```

with `mywrapper` being

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/sh -e "$@"
```

Comment: I now see what you meant by "a Makefile is not a shell script" earlier. It took a while to click. Thanks for your help.